# import date column from excel into SSIS - getting long date format in SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, datetime, ssis, etl

I am trying to import a CSV file into SQL server using SSIS.  There is a date column (formatted as date when file is opened in excel).  Column is `DT_DBDATE` in Flat file manager.  I am trying to load this data into a SQL server date column.  The data is formatted as `1/17/2016`.  I can see in data viewer that the data stays in this format from flat file source to OLE DB Destination but when the data is finally loaded into SQL table the format is changed to `1/17/2016 12:00:00 am`.   How do I get the data to stay as `1/17/2016` in my final destination of SQL server?

Comment: Seems like your import is running fine, as you did not reported any error. You should not worry about the way the data is displayed, since it obviously has the correct value.

Comment: @Laura welcome to stackoverflow, it is good to read the [Tour Page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about this community rules and to obtain the *"informed"* badge.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the destination column data type:

- If the column data type is `datetime` or `smalldatetime`then the time will be displayed.
- If the column data type is `date` (SQL Server 2012+) then time will not be displayed

For more info you can refer to the following link:

- [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

So if you don't need the time part you can change the destination column type to `Date`, or you can just remove the time part when reading the values within an application or a report.